# autocomplete to populate all values on input focus

Tags: json, jquery-ui-autocomplete, onfocus

I have autocomplete textbox whose values are populated using ajax call which returns json data. This works fine with following code lines.

```
$("#searchTitle").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/umbraco/Surface/MyApp/StartSearch",
            type: "POST", dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                debugger
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    debugger
                    return { label: item.Cat_Name };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    messages: { noResults: "", results: "" },
    minLength: 0
});
```

But this function gets called when user type something. Now, I want that when input is focused, all the values from response should be shown in autocomplete. How can I trigger the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by using search event of autocomplete on focus of input.

For example

```
$( "#searchTitle" ).focus(function() {
    // make sure you put space between double quote 
    $( "#searchTitle" ).autocomplete("search", " " ); 
});
```

Comment: my result is from json response... so can you modify the same?